# JavaFX, Creating a thread in the loop

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Can someone advise how to create new threads in a loop. Data are retrieved from the database and I want to make each row was processed in a new thread. Everything happens in the controller JavaFX. You probably need to use the service but I can not find an example of this approach. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want to create a new thread for every row? If you have a million rows, you will have a million threads.
If so, it should be as simple as this:

```
ResultSet rs = ...;
while (rs.next()) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        doSomething();
        Platform.runLater(() -> doSomethingThatUpdatesUI());
    }).start();
}
```

**Update**

An example using javafx.concurrent.Task (only one thread created):

```
Task task = new Task<Void>() {

    @Override
    public Void call() {
        ResultSet rs = ...;
        int max = getSizeOfResultSet(rs);
        int count = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                break;
            }
            updateProgress(count++, max);
        }
        return null;
    }
};
yourProgressBarIfYouHaveOne.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
new Thread(task).start();

task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
    System.out.println("OK, all done!");
    releaseUserInterface();
});
```

Comment: I want to add to every a new thread because a single application until it reads the data it does not work entirely correctly. Thread should be turned on and off for each row. I hope that it will be smoother operation. And in this way I have not tried because I tried to find something with a Task or Service - as recommended for JavaFX.

Comment: If you want a task (from javafx.concurrent package) it is advisable to have only ONE task running (See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm). I will update my answer with an example

Comment: How is one topic that will not work as the previous method? So maybe better to use the 'Service' which can run several times? The documentation is not shared examples of

Comment: I know how to make a thread in the 'Service' single. But when you throw the entire thread loop passing through all the rows that no longer sees me iterative variable "and" loop. And I do not use the loop "while" because later when editing takes into account the +/- 50 rows because they do not need to go through all the rows. Then I have a loop "for"